# How did gothic church architects/builders properly scale up their models to full size churches?

Tags: structural-engineering, structures, building-design, building-physics

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiX2amY7G-I) the author explains how ancient church builders used models to determine the proper shape and order of installation of architectural elements in gothic churches.

From the little I know, I know elements do not scale up linearly but as A*X² of area and B*x³ of volume/weight.

The video does not address how the ancient builders might have tried to figure out the proper actual size of the final elements of the full scale church.
Is there any historical references available shedding light on this matter? If not, what suppositions would the structural engineers/architects amongst you make on this?

Comment: Why would you think their models would have to follow that formula? A model to determine geometry and coordinate plans between workers is useful even if it is not load-representative.  CAD models are used even without structural analysis components these days.

Comment: Sure! I'm just interested to know how they *did* manage to build the proper load bearing structures. Seems like trial and error would have been immensely costly 

Comment: I suggest you research how the basilica in barcelona was designed. My structures professor thought that the gothic cathedrals might have been designed the same way (ballasted inverted string model).

Comment: Here you go https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-the-basement-of-the-sagrada-familia-in-barcelona-spain-houses-many-139240815.html

Comment: @geeheeb Trial and error certainly seems to have been a part of the process, as there are reports of partial collapses (e.g. Beauvais Cathedral) and instances of bulging walls due to insufficient initial buttressing.